# Why does conditional expectation with sigma-field have a constant value on each element of elements in the $\sigma$-field

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

In this problem https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74332/
there is an explict example for conditional expectation with $\sigma$-field,one key step is $E[Y|\mathcal{F}_1](HH)=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_1](HT)$,where $\mathcal{F}_1=\{∅,\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\},Ω\}$ ,but from the definition of conditional expectation with $\sigma$-field,we only have $\int_AYdP=\int_AE[Y|\mathcal{F}_1]dP$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_1$,and $HH$ and $HT$ are both elements of element of $\mathcal{F}_1$,then why does $E[Y|\mathcal{F}_1](HH)=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_1](HT)$ ?

I see some discussions about this question in the comments,but I don't understand what they mean,especially this statement "Ergo, all measurable functions must have the same values on both outcomes"(in the comments of the first answer).Can anyone help to explain this in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not true that $HH$ and $HT$ are both elements of $\mathcal F_1$.  We have $\{HH,HT\}$ is an element of $\mathcal F_1$, but $\{HH,HT\}$ is not the same as $HH$ or $HT$.

The reason we must have $E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HH)=E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HT)$ is because $E[Y|\mathcal F_1]$ must be $\mathcal F_1$-measurable.  Intuitively, that means that knowing the value of $E[Y|\mathcal F_1]$ can give us no more information than $\mathcal F_1$ itself.  Mathematically it means that $\{\omega : E[Y|\mathcal F_1](\omega) \in (a,b)\} \in \mathcal F_1$ for all $a < b$.  Now, if $E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HH) \ne E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HT)$, we could find an interval $(a,b)$ with $E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HH) \in (a,b)$ but $E[Y|\mathcal F_1](HT) \not \in (a,b)$.  This means $HH \in \{\omega : E[Y|\mathcal F_1](\omega) \in (a,b)\}$ but $HT \not \in \{\omega : E[Y|\mathcal F_1](\omega) \in (a,b)\}$.  However, there is no set $A \in \mathcal F_1$ with $HH \in A$ but $HT \not \in A$, so $\{\omega : E[Y|\mathcal F_1](\omega) \in (a,b)\} \not \in \mathcal F_1$, which contradicts the requirement that $E[Y|\mathcal F_1]$ is $\mathcal F_1$-measurable

Comment: Yes,so I say HH  and HT are elements of elements of $F_1$

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are correct.  I misread it.